# Concatenation of regular languages.

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar, regular-language

The concatenation of $L_1$ and $L_2$ denoted by $L_1.L_2$ = $\{uv|u\in L_1\,and\,v\in L_2\}$.
If,
$$L_1=\{a^n|n\geq0\}\,and\,L_2=\{b^n|n\geq0\}$$
Then why is $$L_1.L_2\neq \{a^nb^n|n\geq0\}$$
I am aware that **regular** languages are closed under **concatenation** and $a^nb^n$ is not regular. But why can't we represent $L_1.L_2$ as done above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that the $n$'s in the definition of $L_1$ and $L_2$ are different $n$'s. In other words

$$L_1 = \{\mathtt{a}^{n_1} \mid {n_1} \geq 0\}\quad \text{ and }\quad L_2 = \{\mathtt{b}^{n_2} \mid {n_2} \geq 0\}.$$
or using $x$ and $y$
$$L_1 = \{\mathtt{a}^x \mid x \geq 0\}\quad \text{ and }\quad L_2 = \{\mathtt{b}^y \mid y \geq 0\}.$$

The concatentation is then $$L_1\cdot L_2 = \{\mathtt{a}^{n_1}\mathtt{b}^{n_2} \mid n_1,n_2 \geq 0\} = \{\mathtt{a}^{x}\mathtt{b}^{y} \mid x,y \geq 0\}.$$

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: So we can say $a^{n_1}b^{n_2}$  is regular right?

Comment: @Sidsec9 Yep, $\mathtt{a}^{n_1}\mathtt{b}^{n_2}$ is regular. The non-regularity of $\mathtt{a}^n\mathtt{b}^n$ comes from the fact that the finite automaton can "remember" (or store) only finite amount of information, but $n$ can get arbitrarily high, so the finite automaton cannot ensure that the counts of $\mathtt{a}$'s and $\mathtt{b}$'s are the same. On the other hand, for $\mathtt{a}^{n_1}\mathtt{b}^{n_2}$ the counts can be different, so there is no problem.